# How to strip 3-rd party website so it is displayed better on mobile?

Tags: android, dom, html, mobile, proxy

There is a webiste with free SMS gateway: http://sms.orange.pl/ When visiting this website from mobile handset there is so much crap. I would like to strip this website, hide most of the divs.

- No geasemonkey for mobile: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/769666
- Cannot apply CSS to an iFrame: [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

How can I preserve working **copy of webiste with some divs hidden**?

Comment: So what part of writing an Android app to get a website and change the content before displaying to a user do you need help with?

Comment: So you want to view a website that you have no control of, with most of its content removed and you want to know how to remove that content by writing what? An android app or a website of your own?

Comment: Not really sure which approach is better.

What I want to do - have a clean website on mobile.

I was thinking about removing some divs using GeaseMonkey (but this is not supported on Android).

Tinkering around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help: http://www.labnol.org/internet/setup-proxy-server/12890/

How to setup proxy server on Google App Engine...

Comment: Actually this is a very useful workaround! Thanks :)